# Should I apply Softmax before calculating metrics Precision or similar?

Tags: pytorch, metric, softmax

I am using [PyTorch Lightning](https://www.pytorchlightning.ai/) (there is no tag for this and I don't have enough reputation to create one) and am facing a multi classification problem.

My loss function is [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) which applies softmax internally. So, as I don't have to take care of this, my model prediction output is not a probability vector. Now, in terms of code, a step looks like this:

```
def train_step(self, batch):
    datapoints, labels = batch
    y_out = self(datapoints)
    loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(y_out, labels)
    metric_output = calculate_some_metric(y_out, labels)
```

My question is now, if there is any need to apply softmax manually before calculating the metric. Surely that will probably depend on the metric itself if this is necessary or not... but are there common metrics where this makes a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you should apply softmax or sigmoid (for the binary case).
y_out is what usually called logits. There are metrics like AUC which requires the probability as an input and will not work well with y_out.